# Python list strange behaviour

Tags: python, list

I have in my code:

```
my_list= []

def start()
 my_list = [1, 2, 3]
 for item in my_list:
  print item
```

And it works OK. But if I call to a second function. The 'for' stament only iterates once, only for the first element of the list.

```
my_list= []

def print_list()
 for item in my_list:
  print item     

def start():
 my_list = [1, 2, 3]
 print_list()
```

Why? Any help/tip?

Comment: Your list is empty. Why do you expect the loop to execute any iterations at all?

Comment: @FatalError sorry i edit the code

Comment: [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the `start()` function the name `my_list` is bound to the list `[1, 2, 3]` but this does not override the empty list with the same name (created in line 1), since that list lives in another scope. If you try to access a variable by the name `my_list` from within the `print_list()` function the own scope is checked first (no variable found) than the parent scope (the file) is checked and the empty list is found. This is why no output is printed.

To avoid this shadowing of variables it's useful to pass the variables as arguments instead of defining them again:

```
my_list = []  # is used in your print_list()

def print_list(my_list):
    for item in my_list:  # this is the list passed by start()
        print item

def start():
    my_list = [1,2,3]  # does override my_list but ONLY inside start()
    print_list(my_list)  # passes my_list to print_list
```

you can (and sometimes should) choose your name for the argument as you want it does not need to match the name used in the start() scope.

If you want to go on with programming in python, I would recommend you to think a minute about this or read in the [documentation](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) about scopes of variables.

Comment: `my_list` is defined in the scope of the `print_list()` function, however it is empty.  If it was not defined, there would be an error.

Comment: More correct to say that `my_list = [1, 2, 3]` creates a local binding to the identifier `my_list`, but does not modify the binding in the outer scope.

Comment: thanks for the hints I edited my answer and hope it's correct and still easy to understand now ;)